# What is the preferred approach to building server background processes on the .NET stack?

Tags: .net, windows-services, background

I have a requirement to build features that perform certain background tasks on a server. Things like queue monitoring (which polls constantly) and scheduled tasks for batch jobs. These processes need to have basic functionality such as; restarting if they fail; being configured to have only one process running or multiple processes; maintaining state when idle etc. Azure worker roles seem to tick a lot of boxes - is there an on premise equivalent?

My current plan is to build a set of Windows services in .NET, but they seem so 90's. Is there a better approach that people are using, from MS or Open Source? Are windows services just so darn good that there is no need to use anything else?

Comment: Windows Services to the rescue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows services are still the preferred technology.